# Google Cloud Storage bucket->exists gives 403

Tags: php, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to check if a bucket exists in Laravel PHP.
I am getting a 403 on the exists() method. Why?

See line 160 https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-php/blob/master/Storage/src/Bucket.php

```
$storageClient = new \Google\Cloud\Storage\StorageClient([
    'projectId' => env('GCS_PROJECT_ID'),
    'keyFilePath' => storage_path(env('GCS_KEY_FILE')),
]);
$bucket = $storageClient->bucket('mybucketname');

if (!$bucket->exists()) {
    $bucket = $storageClient->createBucket('mybucketname');
}

{ "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "myaccount@api-project-xxxxxxxxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.buckets.get access to downloads.",
    "errors": [ {
        "message": "myaccount@api-project-xxxxxxxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.buckets.get access to mybucketname.",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "forbidden"
    } ]
} }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your service account does not have the `storage.buckets.get` permission. In order to check whether a bucket exists and then create it, assign `roles/storage.admin` to your service account.

For reference, see:

- [Cloud IAM roles for Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-roles#standard-roles)
- [Cloud IAM permissions for Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-permissions#bucket_permissions)